# Create Event Subscription: "Deployment has failed with the following error: undefined"

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-functions, azure-deployment, azure-eventgrid

I am trying to create a simple scenario using Azure serverless: ingest a file "dropped" into a "folder".

My current thinking is to use a Blob Storage and link it to a Function using an Event Subscription.

I am pretty much trying to follow this tutorial: https://mobilefirstcloudfirst.net/2017/12/connecting-azure-blob-storage-events-using-event-grid/

However I am getting the following error notification when trying to create an event subscription:

> "Deployment has failed with the following error: undefined"

[image]

I am kind of not sure what to do with the error information like "undefined". Is it an Azure bug or is it an output of something?

Comment: Is this a HTTP Trigger based Azure function?  Have you implemented the event subscription validation (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/receive-events)?

Comment: Did you try to create a subscription using CLI?

Answer (score 1):

> My current thinking is to use a Blob Storage and link it to a Function using an Event Subscription.

Based on my understanding, you could create the Azure Event Grid Trigger function to create event subscription, for more information please refer to  [Create and route custom events with the Azure portal and Event Grid](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/custom-event-quickstart-portal).

Before that you need to create the Azure Blob storage in the [Event Grid supported region](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/overview) and choose Topic type Storage Account. For more details, please refer to the screenshot.

[image]

**Note：** If you want to create it with [Azure CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blob-event-quickstart?toc=%2Fazure%2Fevent-grid%2Ftoc.json) or [Powershell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blob-event-quickstart-powershell?toc=%2Fazure%2Fevent-grid%2Ftoc.json), we also could get the tutorial from Azure official document